# Reference request for the fundamental theorem of Picard-Lefschetz theory

Tags: reference-request

I can find no references for the fundamental theorem of Picard-Lefschetz theory (other than a quick mention in the lecture notes of Jonathan Evans: http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/ST-lectures/lecture10.pdf).  Can anybody point me towards anything that gives a precise statement on the existence of vanishing cycles?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Am I misunderstanding your question? [*Book*](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SURV-97). Regards